# Fastest way to share data with different threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, race-condition

Consider the following scenario with Open MP:

We have a pointer `A` pointed to a very large buffer in memory, and we have several threads, one thread (lets call it thread #1) keep updating the contents in `A` whilst other thread, based on signals controlled by #1, processing data stored in `A`.

Which is the fastest way to ensure (assuming the signal that telling other threads the right time to copy `A` is atomic, so no race conditions there):

1. Threads that processing data will always use the udpated data (e.g. no risk of some data were cached in registers etc).
2. Good performance.

Comment: Does there have to be only one buffer?  Can thread #1 queue up several smaller *buffers instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may try read-write lock. Thread #1 holds write lock, and other threads hold read lock. This way all other threads can read in parallel, only read and write are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Does that ensure any read from other threads will results in a memory access instead of try to load some data in registers etc?

Comment: Read lock doesn't care what read operations you actually do. The read operation might be reading from memory, disk, network, etc., depending on your code. Read-write lock only ensure read operations could be in parallel and read/write are mutable exclusive.

Comment: well, the problem is, there are cases when thread 2 try to read some data in memory (which has been changed), and after some compiler optimization, that compiler think these data were already in the register so no memory access, and use old data stored in register instead, I am trying to avoid this condition.